# Definition of induced representation by tensor product

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose there is a finite group $G$ with a subgroup $H$ an some field $K$. If one has a representation of the subgroup, one can construct the induced representation $\rho:=Ind_H^G$ according to Serre's book with looking at the leftcosets of $H$.

If one switch to modules, then the induced module is defined as $K[G] \otimes_{K[H]} L$, with $L$ a $K[H]$ module.

Why exactly is this tensorproduct the module which belongs to $\rho$? Where is the connection to the leftcosets?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a right $K[H]$ module, one has
$$
  K[G]\cong \bigoplus_{c\in G/H} c.K[H]
$$
(one can take $c$ running over representatives of left $H$-cosets), and therefore
$$
  K[G]\otimes_{K[H]}L\cong \bigoplus_{c\in G/H}c.L
$$
as $K$-vector spaces, where the $c.L$ are just label distinct copies of $L$. If you now look what the left $K[G]$ module structure of the left hand side is, you will see that on the right hand side it does what the construction of the induced representation does.